# Javascript Moodle

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, moodle

Hi I am fairly new to moodle. I have been trying to test if my Javascript runs but to no avail. Here is what I have:

In /videojs/amd/src I made a test.js file with a simple command

```
define(['jquery'], function() {
    return {
        init: function() {
            // Put whatever you like here. $ is available
            // to you as normal.
                alert("It changed!!");
        }
    };
});
```

Then I grunt the file and everything succeed, and made minified. But when I go to the page it doesn't run. Now I read [Moodle's Javascript Doc](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Javascript_Modules) and I see it says

```
The idea here is that we will run the 'init' function from our (PHP) code to set things up. This is called from PHP like this...
```

Where do I call this PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the page you are outputting, you need to add a call like this:

```
$PAGE->requires->js_call_amd('PLUGINTYPE_videojs/test', 'init);
```

It's not entirely clear from your example what sort of plugin you are creating, so whichever type you are creating (https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types), you need to put it in the appropriate subdirectory for your site (e.g. /mod/videojs, /local/videojs, etc.), then add some sort of PHP script as the entry point for your plugin and call the js_call_amd function from there.

Comment: Thnk you!

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Media_players

I added it in setup function like it said (/classes/plugin.php) and 
`$page->requires->js_call_amd('media_videojs/test', 'init');`
Did the trick. **Thank you!**